# Send an E-Mail with attachment using JAVA Mail API without storing in local machine

Tags: java, email

I have report in my `jsp` page and I am writing that report in PDF Format.
And I want to send the PDF as E-Mail with attachment, but I don't want store the file in local machine or server, but i want to send an email with the attachment.

Comment: Could you send the email w/attachment, and then delete the local file afterwards?

Answer (score 6):

If you use [Spring's JavaMail API](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/mail.html#mail-javamail-mime), you can do this sort of thing fairly easily (or at least, as easily as the JavaMail API allows, which isn't much). So you could write something like this:

```
JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = ... instantiate and configure JavaMailSenderImpl here
final byte[] data = .... this holds my PDF data

mailSender.send(new MimeMessagePreparator() {
   public void prepare(MimeMessage mimeMessage) throws Exception {
      MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage);
     // set from, to, subject using helper
     helper.addAttachment("my.pdf", new ByteArrayResource(data));
   } 
});
```

The attachment data can be any of Spring's Resource abstractions, `ByteArrayResource` is just one of them.

Note that this part of the Spring API stands on its own, it does not require (but does benefit from) the Spring container.

Answer (score 6):

Since JavaMail 1.4 - mail.jar - contains javax.mail.util.ByteArrayDataSource

- https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/util/ByteArrayDataSource.html
- ( https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/ )
- http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index-138643.html - download location

regards

Comment: Thanks, this was precisely the info I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write your own implementation of `javax.activation.DataSource` to read the attachment data from an memory instead of using one of the included implementations (to read from a file, a URL, etc.). If you have the PDF report in a byte array, you can implement a DataSource which returns the byte array wrapped in a ByteArrayOutputStream.