# Send e-mail in Pdf attachment as stream

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, mime-types

I want to send a Pdf as an e-mail attachment (I am using the JavaMail API ). I have the Pdf (generated by jasper) as an `byte[]`.

```
public InputStream exportPdfToInputStream(User user) throws ParseErrorException, MethodInvocationException, ResourceNotFoundException, JRException, IOException{
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = createJasperPrintObject(user);
        byte[] pdfByteArray = JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(jasperPrint);
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(pdfByteArray);
    }
```

Here is the code that I am using to construct the `MimeBodyPart` that will be the attachment:

```
    if (arrayInputStream != null && arrayInputStream instanceof ByteArrayInputStream) {
        MimeBodyPart attachment = new MimeBodyPart(arrayInputStream);
        attachment.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
        mimeMultipart.addBodyPart(attachment);
    }
```

This code gives me this error:

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: IOException while sending message;
  nested exception is:
    java.io.IOException: Error in encoded stream: needed at least 2 valid base64 characters, but only got 1 before padding character (=), the 10 most recent characters were: "\24\163\193\n\185\194\216#\208="
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The constructor you used is for **parsing** a mime part from the transport.

Your second example should work out right. You may consider

- not to convert to InputStream and back, this will make unnecessary copies
- add a disposition ( e.g. **bp.setDisposition(Part.ATTACHMENT);** )

Comment: @mtraut: You said not to convert it to InputStream and back, but how can I do it without an InputStream?

Comment: use the **ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data, String type)** constructor and the "pdfByteArray"

Comment: @mtraut: Thanks, that is what I have already submitted in my answer. But thanks anyway. I though there is another even simpler way to do it!

Comment: @Atticus - not exactly. in your answer you use the INputStream constructor, which results in another copy...

Comment: @mtraut: ok, now I got it. One more thing...why is the setDisposition method needed? It works fine without setting it.

Comment: Using "disposition" you can try to control the way that a client handles the part. While this is not honoured correctly by all kind of implementations, "attachment" will most definitely result in the expected behavior. While there's little risk with a PDF attachment, "text/html" or "text/plain" attachments may be rendered **inline** within the email if not declared correctly. Consider it good style...

Answer (score 23):

I have found a solution as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502635/send-an-e-mail-with-attachment-using-java-mail-api-without-storing-in-local-machi) thread. It seems that there is a `DataSource` class created just for this purpose. Hope this example will help others also.

```
    if (arrayInputStream != null && arrayInputStream instanceof ByteArrayInputStream) {
        // create the second message part with the attachment from a OutputStrean
        MimeBodyPart attachment= new MimeBodyPart();
        ByteArrayDataSource ds = new ByteArrayDataSource(arrayInputStream, "application/pdf"); 
        attachment.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(ds));
        attachment.setFileName("Report.pdf");
        mimeMultipart.addBodyPart(attachment);
    }
```

Comment: This will completely read the InputStream and the byte array is completely stored in the ByteArrayDataSource. So you will have high memory usage for large attachments. Right ?