# Java memory optimization (how to avoid memory-leak - concrete example)

Tags: java, memory-management, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, iostream

I have created a Pdf in my Java web application and I am sending it as a e-mail attachment.
The Pdf is created as a `byte[]` array. Is it better to wrap it in a `ByteArrayInputStream` or should I leave it as `byte[]`.

Wrapping it might be better for memory deallocation (read the accepted answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592058/how-to-send-byte-as-pdf-to-browser-in-java-web-application) thread), but the downside would be that the `InputStream` (if I am right) creates a copy of the array (read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817083/send-e-mail-in-pdf-attachment-as-stream) ).

Which is better to avoid the possibility of having memory hogs?

Comment: "Memory hug" - my new favourite phrase!

Comment: Why would you worry about memory leaks in a garbage collecting environment? Unless you are aware about some particular bug in the JVM that causes memory leaks to occur, but you haven't mentioned anything like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `ByteArrayInputStream` *wraps* the array, it doesn't copy it. From [the documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html) (of the constructor taking `byte[]`):

> Creates a ByteArrayInputStream so that it uses buf as its buffer array. The buffer array is not copied. The initial value of pos is 0 and the initial value of count is the length of buf.

It's possible that whatever *uses* the input stream will copy it, but `ByteArrayInputStream` itself won't.

I'm not convinced that you're really worrying about a particularly important issue - I don't think it would actually create a memory leak at all, just using a byte array.

Comment: I was reading an answer that mentioned using byte[] instead of InputStream to save the webapp from memory hogs, and I did not know if that is really an issue.

Comment: @Atticus: I certainly wouldn't *assume* it's an issue without understanding why the author of that answer *claimed* it's a "memory hog". I suspect it's to allow the data to stream rather than being all copied into memory - but that may or may not be relevant in your situation. As ever, it's important to understand the context of other answers, and whether that context applies to you.