# java mail as pdf files as attachment

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send an e-mail with a PDF as an attachment. It was including the file but its size was less than what it was on disk, and when trying to open it, it says the file is corrupted.

```
MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
        messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();


        try {
            messageBodyPart.attachFile(new File(filePath+"/"+fileName), "application/pdf", null);

            String message = "file attached. ";            
            messageBodyPart.setContent(message, "text/html");
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
            mail.setMultiBody(multipart);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doing some research i found another topic about sending mail with pdf attachment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4817171/2502992).

He does it by stream but i think that is what you need.

```
if (arrayInputStream != null && arrayInputStream instanceof ByteArrayInputStream) {
    // create the second message part with the attachment from a OutputStrean
    MimeBodyPart attachment= new MimeBodyPart();
    ByteArrayDataSource ds = new ByteArrayDataSource(arrayInputStream, "application/pdf"); 
    attachment.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(ds));
    attachment.setFileName("Report.pdf");
    mimeMultipart.addBodyPart(attachment);
}
```

> You have to write your own implementation of javax.activation.DataSource to read the attachment data from an memory instead of using one of the included implementations (to read from a file, a URL, etc.). If you have the PDF report in a byte array, you can implement a DataSource which returns the byte array wrapped in a ByteArrayOutputStream.
>   [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502635/send-an-e-mail-with-attachment-using-java-mail-api-without-storing-in-local-machi)

Comment: It would be useful to provide any information you found in the link. In future, the link could be broken.

Comment: sorry kinda new to answering, noted. I will update my answer also.

Answer (score 3):

You need **two** MimeBodyParts, one for the main message body and one for the attached file:

```
Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
String message = "file attached. ";
messageBodyPart.setText(message, "utf-8", "html");
multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

MimeBodyPart attachmentBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
attachmentBodyPart.attachFile(new File(filePath+"/"+fileName), "application/pdf", null);
multipart.addBodyPart(attachmentBodyPart);
mail.setContent(multipart);
```