# How to attach Pdf file to mail

Tags: java

I am try to attach a ready pdf file to mail using java,so for that I have try below

```
String filename = "file.pdf";

 ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
??.write(bos);

 DataSource fds = new ByteArrayDataSource(bos.toByteArray(), "application/pdf");
 MimeBodyPart mbp2 = new MimeBodyPart();            
 mbp2.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));   
 mbp2.setFileName(filename);
```

I am ot understand what  will be instead of '??'.
so please suggest me about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`javax.mail.util.ByteArrayDataSource` introduced in JavaMail 1.4 and following are some pointers on same

- [ByteArrayDataSource API](http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/javadocs/javax/mail/util/ByteArrayDataSource.html)
- [Java Mail API](http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/javadocs/)
- [Official Page](http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/)

If you use Spring's JavaMail API, you can do this sort of thing fairly easily (or at least, as easily as the JavaMail API allows, which isn't much).

The attachment data can be any of Spring's Resource abstractions, `ByteArrayResource` is just one of them.

Note that this part of the Spring API stands on its own, it does not require (but does benefit from) the Spring container.

```
JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = ... instantiate and configure JavaMailSenderImpl here
final byte[] data = .... this holds my PDF data

mailSender.send(new MimeMessagePreparator() {
   public void prepare(MimeMessage mimeMessage) throws Exception {
      MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage);
     // set from, to, subject using helper
     helper.addAttachment("my.pdf", new ByteArrayResource(data));
   } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the below code :

```
 if (arrayInputStream != null && arrayInputStream instanceof ByteArrayInputStream) {
    // create the second message part with the attachment from a OutputStrean
    MimeBodyPart attachment= new MimeBodyPart();
    ByteArrayDataSource ds = new ByteArrayDataSource(arrayInputStream, "application/pdf"); 
    attachment.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(ds));
    attachment.setFileName("Report.pdf");
    mimeMultipart.addBodyPart(attachment);
}
```

Comment: but what about arrayInputStream, how to?

Comment: That you can refer here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502635/send-an-e-mail-with-attachment-using-java-mail-api-without-storing-in-local-mach

Comment: I am not get yet,what store in arrayInputStream